# How can I manage sessions with stomp protocol?

Tags: spring, websocket, stomp

I am developing websocket in spring boot, react environment.

I am using stomp protocol and I am storing the session in concurrentHashMap().

This is because if there is no subscribing session at the subscription point, data transmission stops, and when there is more than one, data must be periodically transmitted (published).

```
public final static Map<String, String> subscribeSessions = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

 @Override
    public void postSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel, boolean sent) {

        StompHeaderAccessor accessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
        String sessionId = accessor.getSessionId();

        switch (accessor.getCommand()) {
            case CONNECT:
                break;
            case DISCONNECT:
                break;
            case SUBSCRIBE:
                if(!accessor.getDestination().contains("/user/queue")) {
                    subscribeSessions.put(accessor.getSessionId(), 
                                          accessor.getDestination());
                }
                break;
            case UNSUBSCRIBE:
                subscribeSessions.remove(accessor.getSessionId());
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

I tried to store it in hashMap as below in that one user can subscribe to multiple subscription points as shown below.
Session A - /Topic/ex
Session A - /topic/ex/2

However, this is not possible because hashmap does not allow duplicate keys.

Is there any way to solve this?

Or is there a way to check how many people are subscribing to subscription points?

Comment: Asking a question like "Is there any way to solve this?" is way too broad. You need to focus on a specific, concrete problem.

Comment: @JustinBertram On the contrary, when you pose a problem, asking "is there anyway to solve this" is a perfectly cromulent and answerable question (what matters is whether the problem is within scope). That aside, OP followed up with separate question as an alternative that ought not be ignored.

Comment: The question, "Is there any way to solve this?" is technically a yes or no question. Of course, it's highly unlikely the OP wants a simple "yes" or "no" so the question could be fairly interpreted as "How can I solve this?" Even still, it's not clear what "this" is exactly. Is it broadly how they can "manage sessions with stomp protocol" as noted in the title or just "a way to check how many people are subscribing to subscription points"? The question is poorly worded, unclear, and I think unlikely to elicit an answer. IMO it should be closed. I suppose we'll see if others agree.